# Spreading row indices into columns in R

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table, dplyr

I have a data frame in R in the following format:

```
> old.dat
       id type minDate maxDat eventNum
1    001    A     may   june        1
2    002    B     apr    oct        1
3    002    C     may    nov        2
4    002    B    july    dec        3
```

I want to turn rows into columns, based on `eventNum`.  The max `eventNum` is 3, so if some IDs only have 1 `eventNum`, I want them filled with `NA`.

Goal:

```
      id type1 minDate1 maxDat1 eventNum1 type2 minDate2 maxDat2 eventNum2 type3 minDate3 maxDat3 eventNum3
1    001     A      may    june         1  <NA>     <NA>    <NA>        NA  <NA>     <NA>    <NA>        NA
2    002     B      apr     oct         1     C      may     nov         2     B     july     dec         3
```

Here is a code chunk to bring in the starting point.

```
old.dat <- data.frame(id = c("001","002","002","002"),
                      type = c("A","B","C","B"),
                      minDate = c("may","apr","may","july"),
                      maxDat = c("june", "oct", "nov", "dec"),
                      eventNum = c(1,1,2,3))
```

I wrote a for loop, but its rather slow, and its taking a long time to churn through my data set, so any faster suggestions would be great.  Thanks!

Comment: Your goal is pretty much the worst format I can imagine ... Anyway, both data.table and reshape2/tidyr offer functions for reshaping. Try them out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why? I don't know if I can imagine a situation in which that format will be useful, but here is an approach using `tidyr`.

First, I am saving a list of the new column names to make things easier to pull together:

```
newCols <- c("type", "minDate", "MaxDat")
```

(I will be adding the numbers below).

Then, I am `unite`ing the values you want for each event, `spread`ing the results to get a new column for each `eventNum`, then `separate`ing the results back into separate columns (and appending the number of the event to it)

```
old.dat %>%
  unite(toSpread, type, minDate, maxDat, sep = "::") %>%
  spread(eventNum, toSpread) %>%
  separate(`1`, paste0(newCols, "_1"), sep = "::") %>%
  separate(`2`, paste0(newCols, "_2"), sep = "::") %>%
  separate(`3`, paste0(newCols, "_3"), sep = "::")
```

Returns:

```
   id type_1 minDate_1 MaxDat_1 type_2 minDate_2 MaxDat_2 type_3 minDate_3 MaxDat_3
1 001      A       may     june   <NA>      <NA>     <NA>   <NA>      <NA>     <NA>
2 002      B       apr      oct      C       may      nov      B      july      dec
```

Here is an alternative approach that converts the data to a long format first (with `gather`), then generates the new column names and does the spreading. The complicated `mutate` line assigning factor levels to the new columns is only needed to sort the columns and uses `parse_number` from `readr` to extract the event numbers. If you are OK with the output columns being sorted alphabetically, you can skip that step. This approach is robust to additional event numbers, as it will automatically add events for each unique value in `eventNum`.

```
old.dat %>%
  gather(Metric, Value, type, minDate, maxDat) %>%
  unite(newColHead, Metric, eventNum) %>%
  mutate(newColHead = factor(newColHead
                             , levels =
                               unique(newColHead) %>%
                               {.[order(parse_number(.))]}
                               )) %>%
  spread(newColHead, Value)
```

For this use case, the output is identical to the above.

(And, if you want evidence for why this may be better; note my edit -- I originally mislabeled event numbers 2/3.)

Comment: Thank you for your help! I realize the format is far from optimal but it was required for circumstances out of my control.